# Use UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer for UIScrollView

Tags: uiscrollview, uikit, uigesturerecognizer

I need a paged `UIScrollView` that detects panning from the screen edge in the manner of `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer`, rather than detecting panning everywhere like `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.

I can get the `[scrollView panGestureRecogniser]` instance from `scrollView`, but I can't swap it for an instance of `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` instead.

It's also not possible to change `[[scrollView panGestureRecogniser] delegate]` to an object under my control that could stop scrolling gestures unless they start at an edge, because `UIScrollView` doesn't let you change it's `UIGestureReconiser`'s delegates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Achieving this effect turned out to be easier than I'd expected using a technique I'm already familiar with.

As mentioned in the question, you can use `[myScrollView panGestureRecogniser]` to access a scroll view's panning gesture recogniser. Although you can't change the delegate of this gesture recogniser, you *can* change the view that it uses to initiate gestures from – it need not be the scroll view instance itself.

```
[edgePanGestureHolder addGestureRecognizer: [scrollView panGestureRecognizer]];
```

`edgePanGestureHolder` is just a view that stretches from edge to edge and holds the gesture recogniser for the scroll view.

On top of `edgePanGestureHolder` place another view `innerPanPrevention`. `innerPanPrevention` should not stretch all the way to the screen edges.

With this set up, a pan that starts at the edges will find the scroll view's gesture recogniser in `edgePanGestureHolder`. A potential pan that starts in the middle of the view will look for a gesture recogniser in `innerPanPrevention` and won't find a gesture recogniser, preventing the scroll view from panning.

In my case, I also add `UIGestureRecogniser`s to `innerPanPrevention`. These  drive other scroll views. A pan starting from the screen's edge drives one scroll view, and a pan starting inside the screen drives the other.